# Software to manually lock an optical drive door

Tags: windows, dvd, optical-drive, compact-disc

My toddler likes to come up and push the buttons on my PC when I'm trying to work from home, and sometimes he gets the CD or DVD drive open and nearly breaks it by pulling on the door. Is there some sort of software that I can use to manually lock the optical drive doors, as during CD burning (but without actually burning anything)?

(I'm on Windows, BTW.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [CD/DVD Drive Locker](http://www.softbureau.com/index.html) - Free Drive locker tool to prevent ejects.

Answer (score 0):

```
eject -i 1
```

And to reenable:

```
eject -i 0
```

Comment: Heh. This works on my linux laptop, but not on the Windows machine that I'm actually having this problem on.